# How to determine which points fall within a certain value in a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

I have a shapefile that contains different levels for food security. On top of that, I have mapped points for certain office locations. This is shown below. [image]

The country shapefile is extremely simplistic--the only information it contains are values for the food security index (values 1-5). Because of this, I am unable to perform any kind of spatial join.

I want to single out WHICH points exist in each different value, so I don't think point-in-polygon analysis is sufficient (as far as I can tell, this only gives me certain counts, not which points fall in each polygon).

What I've managed to do is select each food security value from the attribute table and then manually clip the point locations to each one. This is a bit clunky though, as I'm looking to do this for many countries. Is there a tool to achieve this more quickly?

Comment: You should be able to use the 'Vector > Data Management > Join attributes by location' tool - that will give each point the attribute of each food security polygon it falls within. It is a spatial join...

Comment: You are able to do a spatial join because the polygon itself contains the spatial information. The other attributes are not needed for this.

Comment: @mapBaker, thank you! I was only familiar with table joins, but this is a very useful (and obvious!) tool. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Lauren great! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mapBaker pointed out, this feature is located in Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes by Location. Input appropriate fields, and voila. :)